# Open Visual Studio Project in Terminal on Mac

Tags: c#, asp.net, terminal

My Visual Studio Preview has expired and I can't seem to get a new one for my app. Is there any way I can start it from my terminal without opening Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Visual Studio Community to continue developing in it. When you have visual studio build tools installed, you can compile and run it through the console via msbuild.